# Manually adding dependencies to debian/control file

Tags: debian, ubuntu, deb

I'm trying to building an .deb installer for my Linux app. I have it working, except for my app calls to ffmpeg and xjadeo via the command line (but is not linked to them), so when my app is installed, I want them installed too.

My current control file looks like this:

`Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}`

But when I add xjadeo and ffmpeg I get an error:

`Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, ffmpeg, xjadeo`

What is the correct way to specify these dependencies?

```
Package ffmpeg was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `ffmpeg.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'ffmpeg' found
Package xjadeo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xjadeo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'xjadeo' found
```

Comment: You dependencies look good to me. At which step do you get the error message above? It seems like something is looking for a [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) file for ffmpeg. [As far as I can tell Debian doesn't ship such a file](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ffmpeg.pc&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that something is looking for pkg-config data about ffmpeg - which is data about _libraries_. This package only contains _executables_ and documentation, though. I think we need a little more context to help you out here.